# safeAreaInsets.top always returns 0 iPhone X

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

The safeAreaInsets for my view always return correct values for the left (44p), right (44p) and bottom (21p) but always returns 0 for the top. I'm currently trying to retrieve this value in my applications main view controller. No matter where I try and access this value (viewDidLayoutSubviews (), showView () or even in a views layoutSubviews () method) the value won't return what I'm expecting. As far as I can tell from the docs, the top safeZoneInset for the top should be 32p. Anyone else had this issue? I am getting this issue on the actual phone, I am not using the simulator.